# Using WordPress, how can I create custom upload and text fields in the dashboard?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a page where I am listing out the employees of a company.

For each employee, I am showing: A photo, A name, and a paragraph with their bio.

Currently I am hardcoding it all in, but the client wants to be able to add,edit or remove employees in the future. I want to give them the flexibility to add more employees on the page, but I would like to have them enter the name in an input field, the bio in a textarea and the photo in an upload field.

Is there any way I can add a panel in the dashboard where I can somehow dynamically create upload fields and textareas for each employee so that they can enter the necessary information that will get filled into pre-designated areas in a dynamically created div on the page? Perhaps I could list & edit the existing employee entries also there?

I have a feeling it has something to do with custom post types and custom templates, but I can't figure out to  use them together or how to add custom functionality to the dashboard area of wordpress.

Does anyone know how I can achieve my end goal, which is to let the user add, edit, and remove whole sections of content on a page?

Answer (score 1):

check out the [advanced custom fields plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) and the [custom post type ui plugin](http://webdevstudios.com/plugin/custom-post-type-ui/).  this is the easiest way to get everything working and it looks super nice too.  i use them on almost every wordpress project i do.  its a great way to put a gui over some things you'd normally have to manually code.

also, yes, you will need to put a custom page together, but there are plenty of tutorials on how to do that.  the basics of it though, create a page template, add a page named whatever you want in wordpress, and select the template you made as the page's template.  no need to put any content in the page, that's why you made the template.

Answer (score 1):

best way to go would be...

to use the custom post types,

**Step 1:**
open up your functions.php file.. 
paste this in..

```
<?php
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails'); // enables featured images for posts
add_action( 'init', 'register_employee_post_type' );

function register_employee_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'Employees',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Employees' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Employee' ),
                'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Employee' ),
                'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Employee' ),
                'new_item' => __( 'New Employee' ),
                'view' => __( 'View Employee' ),
                'view_item' => __( 'View Employee' ),
                'search_items' => __( 'Search Employees' ),
                'not_found' => __( 'No Employees found' ),
                'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Employees found in Trash' ),
                'parent' => __( 'Employee' ),
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => true,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'rewrite' => array('slug'=>'employee'),
            'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
        )
    );
flush_rewrite_rules();
}
?>
```

> **NOTES:**
>
> this will create a new post type Employees
>   this is setup to only include a few things you might need..
>
> ```
> title  //Employee full name
>
> editor //Enable the tinymce editor for bio
>
> thumbnail //Enable the featured image for use with the bio image
> ```
>
> read through this for more options: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types
>
> feel free to edit the labels closer to what you need..

**Step 2:**
Create a new page template.

```
/* Template Name: Employees */
```

**Step 3:**
Apply template to staff page..

**Step 4:**
Query all custom post type employees, 
print a list of all employees, in any format you want...

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'employees', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ); //?show all
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<div class="entry-content">';
    echo "<h2>".the_title()."</h2>"; //full name
         the_content(); //bio
    echo "<div class='employee_image'>".the_post_thumbnail()."</div>"; //image
    echo '</div>';
endwhile;
?>
```

hope fully that gets you on track :)

Marty

made a [Wordpress Custom Post Type Generator](http://www.martin-gardner.co.uk/wordpress-custom-post-type-generator/)